# How can I get a value from an array by a child array value?

Tags: php

I've a huge problem. Somehow I need to get the `variation_id` from an array based on a value of a child array:

```
$array = [
    [
        'attributes'   => [
            'attribute_art-der-karte' => 'Rot'
        ],
        'variation_id' => '222'
    ],
    [
        'attributes'   => [
            'attribute_art-der-karte' => 'Green'
        ],
        'variation_id' => '221'
    ]
];
```

So in my case I've two things available:

1. The key `attribute_art-der-karte`
2. The value `Rot`

I found nothing here instead of a sorting. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: And what you have tried so far? You have enough reputation and you know the norms of posting a good question. Please add missing details

Comment: @AlivetoDie nothing because I dont know if this is even possible. I've did some research without any results. Thats why I'm asking here. If you take a look at my other questions I always post my tries when I had an idea previously.

Comment: Have you tried using a `foreach()` loop over the array?

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, but how can I use this? I mean when I loop over it, I can just get the child array but how to use the value as reference for the item outside of it?

Comment: @Mr.Jo  my question is in your array multiple `Rot` can be there? Is there any possibility of it?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Not for one key. One key one value otherwise the user entered something wrong.

Comment: @Mr.Jo actually I didn't get `Not for one key. One key one value`, but ok leave it, you found your solution. great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply loop over the array and return the variation ID when your condition is met (an attribute exists with the given key and the given value):

```
function findVariationId(array $array, string $attrName, string $attrValue): ?string {
    foreach ($array as $entry) {
        if (($entry['attributes'][$attrName] ?? null) === $attrValue) {
            return $entry['variation_id'];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/aAOaN)**

Comment: pls update it will work above than 7.0 only.https://3v4l.org/aAOaN

Comment: @AlivetoDie Considering versions up to 7.2 are no longer supported, I think defaulting to providing PHP 7.3+ compatible answers is logical. OP should mention if (s)he's using an older version (doesn't seem to be the case here).

Comment: Jeto still i feel better to point that, in case my answer not working for lower versions.

Answer (score 1):

An additional option using `array_search()` and `array_column()`:

```
<?php 

$array = [
    ['attributes' => ['attribute_art-der-karte' => 'Rot'], 'variation_id' => '222'],
    ['attributes' => ['attribute_art-der-karte' => 'Green'], 'variation_id' => '221']
];

$key = array_search (
    'Rot', 
    array_column(array_column($array, 'attributes'), 'attribute_art-der-karte')
);
echo "variation_id: ". (($key === false) ? 'Not found' : $array[$key]["variation_id"]);

?>
```

Output:

```
variation_id: 222
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use array filter for this

```
<?php
$array = [
    [
        'attributes'   => [
            'attribute_art-der-karte' => 'Rot'
        ],
        'variation_id' => '222'
    ],
    [
        'attributes'   => [
            'attribute_art-der-karte' => 'Green'
        ],
        'variation_id' => '221'
    ]
];

function findByAttribute ($arr, $value) {
    $result = array_filter($arr, function($elem) use($value){
     return $elem['attributes']['attribute_art-der-karte'] == $value;
    });
    
    if ($result) {
       return array_shift($result)['variation_id'];
    }
    return '';
}

var_dump(findByAttribute($array, 'Rot')); // gives '222'
var_dump(findByAttribute($array, 'a')); // returns ''
var_dump(findByAttribute($array, 'Green')); // gives 221
```

Answer (score -1):

You can access the element `variation_id` using `foreach`

```
// One way using loops identify the non-array element
foreach($array as $ele){
    if(!is_array($ele)){
        print_r($ele);
    }
}

// Otherway for direct calling
print_r($array['variation_id']);
```